# 3D kmz using dem + tif

Tags: qgis, 3d, kmz, orfeo-toolbox

I am trying to create a kmz using open source software. I have been testing the orfeo toolbox (https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_KmzExport.html) but it is just creating a flat dataset.

Anyone have tested this one?

Or any other solution?

Comment: What do you mean by 'flatdataset'? Can you givem more info about the command line parameters and also on which input images are you trying to run the application?

Comment: @ManuelGrizonnet I mean, I obtain a flat kmz, with no elevation. So the code I run is: *otbcli_KmzExport -in input_tif_path.tif -out Export_tif_path.kmz -elev dem_folder_path*. I also tested: *otbcli_KmzExport -in input_tif_path.tif -out Export_tif_path.kmz -elev.dem dem_folder_path* and elev.dem is supposed to be the path the folder hosting my dem. I used a geotiff as an input and for the elevation parameter, I used a DEM in a dem format as well as in a geotiff format. Both of these have produced a 2d kmz.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.